# Finding ROI for a periodic repetative fringe pattern

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am trying to detect `ROI` for a fixed repetitive pattern in an image using `opencv C++`.

The ROI which I am trying to find - is shown with red boundary as shown in the pic:

[image]

I tried canny edge detection after blurring but it detects edge of the vertical/horizontal black and white lines. This is not something I am trying to detect.

What is the best approach to my problem?

Comment: Here you can find the box taking the bbox of all non-zero pixels (an erosion first can help to remove small noise)

Comment: are they always axis aligned like in your image? is the size (in the image) varying?

Comment: looks a bit like haar pattern histogram could be a good classifier. But you would have to find the roi candidates first. Maybe it could be attractive to detect the black cross in the middle of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're starting with a binary image you could use

```
findContours()
```

to get the contours for the individual strips. Since there are a couple of solitary pixels from noise you should then filter for size using

```
contourArea(contour)
```

and merge the points of all contours meeting your size criteria into a combined contour. Then get the bounding box for the combined contour:

```
boundingRect(combinedContour)
```